# Finding the cheapest flight algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on my API application where my goal is to find the cheapest flight from city A to city B.

The data structure looks like this:

```
public class Airport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string IATA { get; set; }
    public string ICAO { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude{ get; set; }
    public int Altitude { get; set; }
    public double? Timezone { get; set; }
    public string DST { get; set; }
    public string TzDatabaseTimezone { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}


public class Route
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Airline { get; set; }
    public int? AirlineId { get; set; }
    public string SourceAirport { get; set; }
    public int? SourceAirportId { get; set; }
    public string DestinationAirport { get; set; }
    public int? DestinationAirportId { get; set; }
    public string Codeshare { get; set; }
    public int Stops { get; set; }
    public string Equipment { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Table Route has two foreign keys, SourceAirportId and DestinationAirportId which is primary key in table Airport (Id column).

So basically, input in my API will be city A and city B and my output should be the model which will contain one cheapest flight with prize, stops and all routes, that is all clear to me.

My question is, since this algorithm will not be straightforward to implement, is there any external API I could use to make it easier, or I should create my own algorithm? If that is the case, any code or suggestion how to implement it would be priceless.

Comment: Why not implementing an algorithm? this is a simple Dijkstra problem which should be easily implemented (to prevent you from any cost of using other api).

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud Well to be honest, I have never heard of Dijkstra problem. Just took a brief look, it doesnt seems to easy for implementation

Comment: @vidata don't let that stop you, algorithms are quite fun and easy to learn, I'm sure you'll know your way around the solution as soon as you read about the algorithm, plus there are tuns of already implemented versions of Dijkstra's algorithms to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a quick look at your problem it looks like a very good way to implement an algorithm which will be in your favor.

The description of the problem looks easily like a well-known algorithm [Dijkstra's Algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

A quick overview:

Dijkstra's algorithm is an SSSP Algorithm (Single Source Shortest Path) which in your case the source will be the source airport and the destination is the destination airport and the graph will be made of (Airports as nodes, and Routes as edges).

Thus implementing the algorithm will be quite useful for your case.

The main benefit of the algorithm is its runtime complexity which is great for your case `O(|E| + |V| log(|V|) ); where V is the number of nodes (airports) and E is the number of edges (routes)`

If any further information is needed, I'll be glad to help!

Comment: Three and a half years later, I realized that I didn't accept this answer as correct one. But it is the correct one, Dijkstra algorithm is the way to go here :)